# Validar una dirección IP con Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, ip

Tengo esta expresión regular para validar si una cadena puede ser una dirección IP.

```
/\b(?:(?:2(?:[0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(?:(?:2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]))\b/gi
```

Funciona bastante bien pero no me funciona para el caso que me inserten una IP del tipo **01.02.01.03**, **116.73.190.57.53**,  **-242.42.190.186**, **73.230.178.00**.

Este es mi código:

```js
function isValidIP(str) {
    var reg = /\b(?:(?:2(?:[0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])\.){3}(?:(?:2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5])|[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]))\b/gi
    return reg.test(str)
}


console.log(isValidIP("73.230.178.00"));
console.log(isValidIP("3.05.08.01"));
console.log(isValidIP("-73.230.178.00"));
console.log(isValidIP("116.73.190.57.53"));
```

También me gustaría como hacerlo correctamente con una función. Intente con esta pero no me funciona para los **01.02.5.4**.

```js
function isValidIP(str) {
    let verdad = str.split('.').map(n => +n).filter(n => {
        return (n >= 0 && n < 256 && Number)
    })
    return verdad.length == 4 ? true : false
}

console.log(isValidIP("0.0.a.0"));
console.log(isValidIP("01.02.0.0"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para empezar haces bien en emplear una función javascript para validar la IP, no es correcto dejar todo el trabajo al regex.

Con regex te necesitarías algo como:

```
^((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$
```

Dicha regex se puede probar en:

https://www.debuggex.com/r/-EDZOqxTxhiTncN6/1

Solución obtenida de la respuesta de **Sllouyssgort** en [Validating IPv4 addresses with regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25969006/4832311)

Citando al [experto en regex de la pagina](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/127/mariano):

> ...no uses regex para algo tan sencillo, utilizando una expresión regular
>   estarías haciéndolo muchas veces más lento...

Pero para resolverlo puedes apoyarte en regex, con una función js de la siguiente forma:

```js
function isValidIP(str) {
    let verdad = str.split('.');
    if(verdad.length != 4)
      return false;
    for(i in verdad){
      if(!/^\d+$/g.test(verdad[i])
      ||+verdad[i]>255
      ||+verdad[i]<0
      ||/^[0][0-9]{1,2}/.test(verdad[i]))
        return false;
    }
    return true
}

console.log('aceptar:');

console.log(isValidIP("127.0.0.1"));
console.log(isValidIP("192.168.1.1"));
console.log(isValidIP("192.168.1.255"));
console.log(isValidIP("255.255.255.255"));
console.log(isValidIP("0.0.0.0"));

console.log('rechazar:');

console.log(isValidIP("30.168.1.255.1"));
console.log(isValidIP("127.1"));
console.log(isValidIP("192.168.1.256"));
console.log(isValidIP("-1.2.3.4"));
console.log(isValidIP("3...3"));
console.log(isValidIP("0.0.a.0"));
console.log(isValidIP("01.02.0.0"));
console.log(isValidIP("1.1.1.01"));
console.log(isValidIP("1e0.1e1.1e2.2e2"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

---

**Explicación:**

Una IP valida se compone de 4 números, así que si el tamaño es distinto es invalida.

```
if(verdad.length != 4)
return false
```

luego la expresión regular para que solo acepte números (sin otros caracteres) es:

```
/^\d+$/g
```

de modo que si un numero de la IP no encaja es invalida.

Luego cada numero no debe ser mayor a 255

```
+verdad[i]>255
```

ni menor a 0

```
+verdad[i]<0
```

por ultimo para evitar los números que inician con 0 (01, 002, etc.) puedes usar esta regex (aunque algunas paginas indican que son validos):

```
/^[0][0-9]{1,2}/
```

De esa forma puedes validar una dirección IP con javascript, saludos.

Comment: Se que se pueden unir las 2 regex en una sola para usar `test()` una sola vez, solo la hice separada para mejorar la explicación.

Comment: WoW gracias @the-breaker deberias pagarte... Muy buena repuesta..

Comment: en este caso **1e0.1e1.1e2.2e2** me esta regresando true

Comment: @IsraelGonzález ya lo vi, no habían tomado en cuenta ese caso en otras respuestas, lo puedes resolver colocando `||!Number.isInteger(+verdad[i])` al `if`, puedo agregarlo a la respuesta o si gustas lo puedes agregar también.

Comment: si lo agrego... seria bueno que este en la respuesta por si le sirve a alguien mas..

Comment: añadiendo eso no me funciona @the-breaker

Comment: @IsraelGonzález ok ya lo revise, se puede emplear otra regex en lugar de la primera para que solo acepte dígitos, con eso ya queda resuelto ese caso también.